# How python handles decorators during class construction

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm doing some tests with decorators on class methods. Following is a code sample:

```
def my_decorator(prefix):
    def my_command(prefix):
        print(f'my_command is called with {prefix}')
        return lambda func: print(prefix)
    return my_command

class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        print('MyClass ctr')

    @my_decorator('cmd 1')
    def _method_1():
        pass

    @my_decorator('cmd 2')
    def _method_2():
        pass

print("=================")
m = MyClass()
```

When I execute the code I got the following output:

```
my_command is called with <function MyClass._method_1 at 0x7f99a1f1f040>
my_command is called with <function MyClass._method_2 at 0x7f99a1f1f160>
=================
MyClass ctr
```

It seems that the decorators of all the methods are called before calling the class ctr (`__init__` method).

Is this the default behavior? Why are decorators being called during the class creation process?

Comment: The decorators are called as soon as the method is created, which is while the class is being created and therefore _definitely_ before any instance is being initialised.

Comment: You can differentiate between things being run before instantiation and things being run early in instantiation by inserting a `print()` statement between the class definition and the last line of code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the response. So in my obj __dict__ I'll get the decorated methods before __init__ is called right?

Comment: In `MyClass.__dict__`? Yes, you'd see something like `'_method_1': <function my_decorator.<locals>.my_command.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x...>`